# Je ne trouve pas la règle de différence entre le gérondif et le participe présent

Tags: gérondif

Bonjour, je ne trouve pas la règle de différence entre le gérondif et le participe présent.

''Il se promène en captant''(simultanéité) 
''Répondant aux journalistes, le ministre a confirmé qu'il irait en Chine prochainement.''(simultanéité)

''Il a refusé craignant d'être trompé.''(cause-pourquoi) 
''En ayant sommeil, il se couche sur le lit.''(cause-pourquoi)

''Il veut, ignorant tout, parler de tout.''(bien que) 
''Tout en travaillant beaucoup, il sort très souvent.''(bien que)

Mais souvent, on ne peut pas remplacer les deux.

Comment: La raison est simple, et trouvable en faisant le moindre effort à la google: le gérondif en français se forme avec en + le participe présent. Il semblerait que votre question porte plutôt sur: l'adjectif verbal et le participe présent. Lá, je pense que vous allez trouver des réponses par le même chemin.

Answer (score 2):

Réponse rapide:

Le participe présent est une forme verbale qui marque une action ***et qui peut avoir un complément d'objet ou de circonstance***. Quant à l'adjectif verbal, il marque l'état, la qualité. Il a la valeur d'un véritable qualificatif, et s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec le nom.

Au besoin, vous pouvez consulter cette page : Le participe présent, l'adjectif verbal et le gérondif.

http://www.espacefrancais.com/le-participe-present-ladjectif-verbal-et-le-gerondif/

Il y a une différence entre l'adjectif verbal et le participe présent. ***Quant au gérondif, il se forme toujours par EN + LE PARTICIPE PRÉSENT. Dès qu'il y a EN + participe présent, il s'agit d'un gérondif.***

Vos phrases:
Il se promène ***en captant*** [omission?] (simultanéité)//c'est un gérondif.

***Répondant aux journalistes***, le ministre a confirmé qu'il irait en Chine prochainement. (simultanéité)// C'est un participe présent marquant une action avec  un complément d'objet.

Il a refusé ***craignant d'être trompé***.//C'est un participe présent marquant une action.

***En ayant sommeil***, il se couche sur le lit.//C'est encore un gérondif.

Il veut, ***ignorant tout***, parler de tout.//participe présent marquant une action avec complément d'objet

Tout **en travaillant** beaucoup, il sort très souvent.//Gérondif

Adjectif verbal: **Le train sortant** était en retard.

**Les filles dansantes** n'étaient pas celles sur le plateau.

**Les hommes assis** ne parlaient pas beaucoup.

NB: pour voir s'il s'agit d'un adjectif verbal, remplacer l'adjectif verbal par un verbe; Les hommes qui étaient assis, la fille qui dansaient, le train qui sortait, etc.

Comment: Je me demande surtout les usages différents

Comment: Certainement, c'est trouvable.